# How to search within the *content* of my bookmarks' webpages? (not by title or url)

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm trying to search for a term that is in one of my bookmarked sites.

For instance, if I wanted to search on the term "Obama" and restrict my query to the New York Times web site, I know I could type this into the main URL/Search bar in Chrome:

obama site:nytimes.com

I'm wondering if there's a way to change that so that it's effectively:

obama site:any one of the sites in my Chrome bookmark folder